# Surrogate key often break BCNF?

Tags: database-theory

```
CREATE TABLE issue (
    ID varchar(36) not null,
    title varchar(255), 
    issue_num varchar(255),
    release_year year,
    comic_language_code varchar(3),
    edition varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

From the example SQL code above, it breaks BCNF if the ID is a surrogate key that can uniquely identify all rows in the table, because of the functional dependencies

```
{ID, title} -> {issue_num, release_year, language, edition}
{ID, issue_num} -> {title, release_year, language, edition}
```

and so on. But tables that have more than two columns with a surrogate key as primary key break BCNF. As you can see, in the example there are six columns. When create the FDs some of their LHS could be {ID}, {ID, title}, {ID, issue_num}, {ID, release_year}, and so on (not sure if this correct). Those LHS works as determinants, and because BCNF requires all determinant to be a candidate key without overlap on LHS. In this case ID is overlapped, so it is not BCNF.

According to my understanding there are two criteria that make table in BCNF. First, all determinants are candidate keys. Second, there must not be overlap on LHS of functional dependency of those candidate keys.

In the example case there is an overlap attributes, which is the ID column, and this made me think this table is not BCNF.

Comment: `But tables that have more than two columns with a surrogate key as primary key` please elaborate on this point

Comment: @RinkeshP edited, hope this help clarify.

Comment: the functional dependencies which include `ID` would be superkeys, and since `ID` is a key, all other dependencies would involving it would be trivial, and hence, not break BCNF.